# Кеширование медленного запроса к БД в wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

На сайте согласно `Query Monitor` есть медленный запрос, который создается плагином `Wordpress Download Manager`. Источник вызова - `count_user_posts`

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM wp_posts
WHERE ( ( post_type = 'wpdmpro'
AND ( post_status = 'publish'
OR post_status = 'private' ) ) )
AND post_author = 1
```

Почитав в интернете информацию, понял, что его можно закешировать `wp_cache_get`, тем более на сервере используется редис. Но не понял, как это сделать правильно. Создать функцию и вставить в `function.php`? Нашел такой пример, но затрудняюсь его подредактировать на свои данные.

```php
function prefix_get_post_count( $post_status = 'publish' ) {
    $cache_key = 'prefix_post_count_'. $post_status;
    $_posts = wp_cache_get( $cache_key );
    if ( false === $_posts ) {
        $_posts = $wpdb->get_var(
                    $wpdb->prepare(
                        "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type = 'post' AND post_status = %s",
                        $post_status
                    ));
  
        wp_cache_set( $cache_key, $_posts );
    }
  
    return $_posts;
}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какой должен быть код.

Comment: Скажите, этот медленный запрос как-то влияет на работу WordPress?

Comment: Страница медленнее грузится, нагрузка на БД повышается.

Comment: Чтобы редис кешировал ВП нужно использовать плагин для этого. В самом же QM есть информация об [не]использовании кеша.

Comment: На сайте используется плагин для редиса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Код кеширования должен выглядеть так:

```php
function prefix_get_post_count( $author ) {
    global $wpdb;

    $cache_key = 'wpdmpro_post_count';
    $count    = wp_cache_get( $cache_key );

    if ( false === $count ) {
        $count = $wpdb->get_var(
            $wpdb->prepare(
                "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->posts
                WHERE ( ( post_type = 'wpdmpro' AND ( post_status = 'publish' OR post_status = 'private' ) )
                AND post_author = %d )",
                $author
            )
        );

        wp_cache_set( $cache_key, $count );
    }

    return $count;
}
```

Но не торопитесь его применять. Закешировать - дело нехитрое. Основная проблема в кешировании - вовремя инвалидировать кеш. Особенно она важна, когда установлен и подключен Redis. Т.е. ваш запрос, будучи закеширован, будет отдавать один и тот же результат вечно.

Вам надо понять, как добавляются посты типа 'wpdmpro'. Если стандартными функциями WordPress, то надо использовать хуки 'save_post', 'post_updated', 'wp_trash_post', 'untrash_post', 'delete_post' для перехвата событий, проверять на них тип поста и сбрасывать кеш, если этот тип 'wpdmpro'.